# Cython: working with C++ streams

Tags: python, c++, io, stream, cython

**The Problem**

How does one use c++ streams (like `std::ifstream` or `ostream`) from Cython? In c++, you could do the following:

```
std::ofstream output { filename, std::ios::binary };
output.write(...);
```

How would you achieve the same in Cython?

**Current status**

I have wrapped the structures from fstream in Cython so that I can use their names in function declarations, but the tricky part is to use (wrap in Cython, perhaps) the write method and to create the streams. I haven't found any code examples on the internet.

P.S.
I know one possible answer would be to just use Python's IO but I need to pass/return the streams to and from C++ code that I'm interfacing with.

This is the code that wraps the stream declarations:

```
cdef extern from "<iostream>" namespace "std":
    cdef cppclass basic_istream[T]:
        pass

    cdef cppclass basic_ostream[T]:
        pass

    ctypedef basic_istream[char] istream

    ctypedef basic_ostream[char] ostream
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't much particularly special about the c++ iostreams compared to wrapping any other C++ class. The only tricky bit was getting access to `std::ios_base::binary`, which I did by telling Cython that `std::ios_base` was a namespace and not a class.

```
# distutils: language = c++

cdef extern from "<iostream>" namespace "std":
    cdef cppclass ostream:
        ostream& write(const char*, int) except +

# obviously std::ios_base isn't a namespace, but this lets
# Cython generate the correct C++ code
cdef extern from "<iostream>" namespace "std::ios_base":
    cdef cppclass open_mode:
        pass
    cdef open_mode binary
    # you can define other constants as needed

cdef extern from "<fstream>" namespace "std":
    cdef cppclass ofstream(ostream):
        # constructors
        ofstream(const char*) except +
        ofstream(const char*, open_mode) except+

def test_ofstream(str s):
    cdef ofstream* outputter
    # use try ... finally to ensure destructor is called
    outputter = new ofstream("output.txt",binary)
    try:
        outputter.write(s,len(s))
    finally:
        del outputter
```

The other thing to add is that I haven't bothered with the full templated class heirarchy - that might be useful if you also want the `wchar` variants, but it's much easier to only tell Cython about the classes you're actually using.