# How to build in Cython an iostream object (e. g. cout) and pass it to a c++ function?

Tags: python, c++, cython, iostream

I'm trying to wrap the following C++ class:
print.h

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class ControlParameters
{
public:
    ControlParameters();
    ~ControlParameters();
    void Initialize(string input, ostream& log);
};
```

print.cpp

```
#include "print.h"
#include <iostream>

ControlParameters::ControlParameters()
{
}
ControlParameters::~ControlParameters()
{
}
void ControlParameters::Initialize(string input, ostream& log)
{
 log<<"Output = "<< input <<endl;
}
```

My String.pyx looks as follows:

```
from libcpp.string cimport string
cdef extern from "<iostream>" namespace "std":
    cdef cppclass ostream:
    ┆   ostream& write(const char*, int) except +

cdef extern from "print.h":
    cdef cppclass ControlParameters:
    ┆   ControlParameters() except +
    ┆   void Initialize(string, ostream&)

cdef class PyControlParameters:
    cdef ControlParameters *thisptr
    def __cinit__(self):
    ┆   self.thisptr = new ControlParameters()
    def __dealloc__(self):
    ┆   del self.thisptr
    def PyInitialize(self, a,b):
            self.thisptr.Initialize(a, b)
```

After I compiled the String.pyx I get the following Error:

```
Compiling String.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing String.pyx

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.thisptr = new ControlParameters()
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr
    def PyInitialize(self, a,b):
            self.thisptr.Initialize(a, b)
                                      ^
------------------------------------------------------------

String.pyx:18:39: Cannot convert Python object to 'ostream'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    language="c++"
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1039, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1161, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: String.pyx
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984078/cython-working-with-c-streams) that I have to build my own ostream class in order to get an ostream object. But how do I define this object? 
I think i need a function which converts my python object to an object of ostream. How could I implement such a function?

Comment: What do you actually want to do with the output? Send it to a file? send it to standard out? Have a choice between the two?

Comment: @ DavidW I want to send it to standard out. In c++ I would pass a cout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you always want to send it to cout then the easiest way is to do this in Cython and not deal with the second argument in Python. Add cout to your `cdef extern`:

```
cdef extern from "<iostream>" namespace "std":
  # define ostream as before
  ostream cout
```

Then in do PyInitialize as:

```
def PyInitialize (self, a):
  self.thisptr.Initialize(a,cout)
```

That saves the effort of writing a full ostream wrapper class for Cython.